# Проблема с конструкцией if-elif-else

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
age = int(input("Сколько лет: "))
if age < 2:
    msg = 'Младенец'
elif age >= 2 < 4:
    msg = 'Малыш'
elif age >= 4 < 13:
    msg = 'Ребёнок'
elif age >= 13 < 20:
    msg = 'Подросток'
elif age >= 20 < 60:
    msg = 'Взрослый'
elif age >= 60:
    msg = 'Пожилой человек'
else:
    print('None')
print(f'Тебе {age} лет и ты у нас {msg}!')
```

Решаю задачу по Python и не могу понять почему при указании возраста ответ постоянно с первого *elif* ,берется при любой цифре за исключением if если указать число < 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что ваши `elif` *на самом деле* выглядят так:

```
(age >= 2) < 4
```

а `age >= 2` это либо `1` либо `0` -> это всегда `<4`.
Вот так работать будет:

```
elif 2 <= age < 4:
```

или вот так:

```
elif age >= 2 and age < 4:
```